# How to make Level Increase With Difficulty Based on Bullet Speed?

Tags: java

```
if(timer.timerEvent(1)) {
```

This part of code controls the speed of the bullets and how quickly they fire.

```
if (level.isComplete()) {
        completeTimer.tick(delta);
        if (completeTimer.isEventReady()) {
            level.reset();
        }
    }
```

This part controls what happens with the timer after the level is completed. How would i make it so that the timer.timerEvent can increase by 100 every time the level is completed, before the level is reset again

Comment: That called a variable I believe. That you want to increment based on some condition. I can't really help you more because I don't see the problem here. If you are able to implement that program, you should be able to manage this simple incremented variable

Comment: Eg. int bulletSpeed = 1; if(timer.timerEvent(bulletSpeed){ bulletSpeed += 1;}

Comment: @Kyle: you need to do a good amount of programming before asking here